# Как на Mac OS сделать скриншоты с оформлением терминала?

Tags: macos, macbook

Очень часто в презентациях, статьях видел скриншоты кода на фоне терминала или редактора кода mac OS. Как это вообще можно сделать?

Примеры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: пример]

Comment: Ну, просто нарисовать в любом графическом редакторе?

Comment: @andreymal Возможно. Но думаю есть более легкий способ) Никак не могу найти

Comment: Если у Вас mac os можно установить monosnap и сделать скрин выбранного окна, будет как Вам нужно. При наведении на необходимое окно или приложение, заметите голубую рамочку, кликаете и готово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сделать скриншот окна, нужно сначала нажать сочетание Command+Shift+4 (в этом режиме вы сможете выбрать часть экрана для скриншота), затем нажать на  Space, курсор станет значком камеры, и теперь при наведении на окно какой-либо программы оно будет подсвечиваться. После этого кликаете на это окно мышью и его скриншот сохраняется на рабочий стол.

Answer (score 0):

Вам уже ответил @schmidt9 , но добавлю, что есть еще удобные комбинации:

- `command + shift + 4` (выбранная область экрана или через пробел одно из окон [[описание на сайте apple](https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/HT201361)])
- `command + shift + 3` (скриншот всего экрана [[описание на сайте apple](https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/HT201361)])
- `command + shift + 5` (выбрать что скопировать: часть экрана, окно на экране, а также переключиться на запись видео с экрана всего или выбранной области [[описание на сайте apple](https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/HT208721)])